# InstancePerLifetimeScope vs OwnedByLifetimeScope

Tags: autofac

What's the difference between the two. Is the latter a newer option? I think that I haven't seen it before.

The document says that the latter will dispose IDisposables, but IIRC that's been the behavior of InstancePerLifetimeScope  too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OwnedByLifetimeScope` and `InstancePerLifetimeScope` set different properties of the registration. If you look at the source code, you'll see:

```
    ... OwnedByLifetimeScope()
    {
        RegistrationData.Ownership = InstanceOwnership.OwnedByLifetimeScope;
        return this;
    }
```

and

```
    ... InstancePerLifetimeScope()
    {
        RegistrationData.Sharing = InstanceSharing.Shared;
        RegistrationData.Lifetime = new CurrentScopeLifetime();
        return this;
    }
```

In the case of `OwnedByLifetimeScope`, that is actually the default value, so setting it explicitly would usually be a no-op, unless some other code was explicitly changing it to `ExternallyOwned`.